# Error when installing rabbitMQ server on Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: ubuntu, installation, rabbitmq

When I install rabbitMQ in synaptic via the following command

```
sudo apt-get install rabbitmq-server
```

it returns an error:

```
Starting rabbitmq-server: FAILED - check /var/log/rabbitmq/startup_log, _err
rabbitmq-server.
invoke-rc.d: initscript rabbitmq-server, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing rabbitmq-server (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 rabbitmq-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Going to the logs, it says the following:

```
Error: {cannot_connect_to_epmd,"herman-desktop",address}
```

while my `/etc/hosts` is defined as follows:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
::1 herman-desktop localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
127.0.1.1 herman-desktop
```

What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have the "herman-desktop" configured in /etc/hosts to the localhost address in ipv6 only, since rabbitmq is running ipv4 it won't be able to connect, edit /etc/hosts and add herman-desktop (your machine name I suppose) to the line of 127.0.0.1 (localhost on ipv4)

Also unless you have 127.0.1.1 configured on your machine it looks like a type to me :)

Comment: Thanks, but it's still not working. Could you please provide an example of how that 127.0.0.1 line should look? Also, 127.0.1.1 is really configured, but don't ask me why

Comment: It seems ubuntu 12.04 configures 127.0.1.1 to the hostname of the of the pc by default

Answer (score 7):

Best way is to tell rabbitmq to not to look for hostname. You can do that using rabbitmq config file.

edit config, create it if it does not exist

```
vim /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf
vim /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf (in later versions of RabbitMQ)
```

Add following entries:

```
NODENAME=rabbit@localhost 
NODE_IP_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1
```

Comment: thx, was stuck with starting the server, this solved it!

Comment: This did it for me, seems to be the least invasive solution.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I changed the hostname while installing chef-server. I reverted back to the old hostname, killed running rabbitmq processes, purged rabbitmq package, then re-run chef-solo bootstrap of chef-server.